# How to stop stream without putting down the Nodejs server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to close a Twitter stream. The problem is that it puts down my server and I have to restart it. Is there way to close the stream without putting down the Nodejs (express) server.
Here is the erorr I am getting:

```
file:///mnt/c/Users/john%20john/Desktop/tweetNode/controllers/utils.js:21
    throw new Error('something bad happened');
Error: something bad happened
    at Parser.<anonymous> (file:///mnt/c/Users/john%20john/Desktop/tweetNode/controllers/utils.js:21:11)
    at Parser.emit (node:events:376:20)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/Users/john john/Desktop/tweetNode/node_modules/twitter/lib/twitter.js:288:14)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:388:22)
    at TLSSocket.socketCloseListener (node:_http_client:442:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:388:22)
    at node:net:661:12
    at TCP.done (node:_tls_wrap:564:7)
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /mnt/c/Users/john john/Desktop/tweetNode
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node app.js

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/johnjohn/.npm/_logs/2020-12-06T02_19_10_092Z-debug.log
```

**Here is the code**

```
import Twitter from 'twitter';
import ck from 'ckey';

let twitter = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: ck.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
  consumer_secret: ck.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
  access_token_key: ck.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY,
  access_token_secret: ck.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
});

export const stream = (term, clients) => {
  let stream = twitter.stream('statuses/filter', { track: term });
  stream.on('data', function (tweet) {
    console.log('tweetsJohn: ');
    broadcast(clients, JSON.stringify(tweet));
  });

  stream.on('error', function (error) {
    // throw error;
    throw new Error('something bad happened');
  });

  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('Closing stream...');
    stream.destroy();
  }, 1000);

  // return stream;
};
```

Comment: you should print the `error` object in your error callback to see if there is a field indicating the origin of the error. I think you should not throw an Error if the error is due to an explicit call to the destroy method

Comment: my mistake was that I was throwing a new error. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, don't throw an error from your `error` event handler.  Any time an exception is uncaught, the node process will crash.  So as written, your code *guarantees* that your app will crash any time something goes wrong with the Twitter connection.

You probably want to log the error and then have a way to recover the connection and/or notify whoever instantiated this code that something went wrong.

Next, notice the [`stream.destroy()` docs](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_destroy_error):

> After this call, the writable stream has ended and subsequent calls to `write()` or `end()` will result in an `ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED` error.

Presumably, something is calling `write` after you've destroyed, which is what is causing the `error` event.

However, you should not be getting an `error` event as part of a normal shutdown.

Comment: I don't see a close method in the documentation. Does it really exist ?

Comment: Oops, I was thinking of something else, sorry.  You're right, a `Readable` consumer only has the `destroy()` method available.  Still, you shouldn't get errors for using it.

Comment: I was wondering why I can only pause and start consequently only two times then I am getting an error. ```status: 420,
    statusText: 'Enhance Your Calm'```

Comment: ```SyntaxError: Unexpected token E in JSON at position 0```

Comment: That's the Twitter API server rate limiting you.

Comment: ```source: 'Exceeded connection limit for user'```

Comment: I don't know -- you'd have to ask Twitter support.

Comment: After calling stream.destroy(), you can recreate the stream, if you wait long enough - see the "should reuse stream N times" test. Note that Twitter may return a "420 Enhance your calm" error if you switch streams too fast. There are no response headers specifying how long to wait, and the error, as well as streaming limits in general, are poorly documented. Trial and error has shown that for tracked keywords, waiting 20 to 30 seconds between re-creating streams was enough. Remember to also set up the .on() handlers again for the new stream.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to removing the listeners before destroying the stream ?

```
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('Closing stream...');
  stream.removeAllListeners('data');
  stream.removeAllListeners('error');
  stream.destroy();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I tried it as per your code but it does not work. Though I tried a different npm package npm twitter-lite and it works fine. ```process.nextTick(() => stream.destroy());```